# What's the significance of the hoofed figure walking a fish in "A Day at the Park"?

Tags: symbolism, comics, kostas-kiriakakis

["A Day at the Park"](http://kiriakakis.net/comics/mused/a-day-at-the-park) is an excellent philosophical comic by Kostas Kiriakakis, featuring two rather odd-looking creatures discussing the merits of questions and answers. (It applies very well to some discussions on Stack Exchange, notably ["We're Rewarding the Question Askers"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1).) The two main characters, the young one with his questions and the old one with his answers, are almost always the focus of the comic, but a few frames pull out to focus on a passerby, a tall figure with hooved feet "walking" a fish on a leash:

[image: a small frame zoomed in on the Answerer, another small frame featuring a fish on a leash; a wide frame with the Asker and Answerer in the background and a pair of hooves in the foreground; a small frame with the Asker and Answerer in the foreground and a tall horned figure in the background, a small frame zoomed in on the Answerer]

**Do these extra character(s) signify anything?** Is the figure with horns and hooves supposed to be demonic? What does it mean that the fish is floating in mid-air? Is there any meaning to this beyond an extra feature of the world drawn around the Asker and the Answerer?

Comment: Some random thoughts: Given the context, I feel like the hoofed figure (I'll assume it's a goat) could represent the question and the fish the answer. Fish are associated with hidden things (underwater). The goat searched for&caught it, brought the fish "to the surface" and now "has" an answer, enforced by the leash. I guess the fact the fish is floating could just represent that it's alive, i.e. the answer to the question is not useless (yet), until it doesn't serve the goat anymore. I don't see any connection between a Q and a goat. goat & fish might be Capricorn or opposites (Q/A,God/Satan)